# vSphere 5.5 Data Storage Recovery from deleted VM

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, partition, vsphere-client

I have deleted one of my VMs but without detaching or making a snapshot of the storage attached to it. Is it possible to assign the same storage to a new VM? I was running CentOS 7 on the old one. In the past I have created a new disk with about 1Tb of data and then I have created probably 4 or 5 partitions (/home, /root, /boot, swap and /var). I only want to preserve the /home partition. Is it possible to allocate the same virtual disk to the new VM and how to do that? I am using vsPhere Client 5.5. What are these Virtual Device nodes? Are they the individual partitions? Also when I go to the datastore browser I see a lot of vmdk's is there a way to attach these vmdks to the the new VM and check them. I just presume I can delete some of them to free some space.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently when you delete the VM it doesn't delete the vmdk (virtual machine disk) file, so you can add it manually to the new VM and eventually mount it to a directory of your choice. You can also manage the datastore from the vSphere client and delete the not used vmdk files if needed.